# Access Variable From Any File

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an objective-c/xcode project with several header and implementation files.  I'd like to declare a variable that I can read and change from any file associated with the project.  I tried doing `extern int val = 0;` in a header, but that lead to a linker error.

Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing and accessing an `int` in and iOS app, I recommend using `NSUserDefaults`.

You can set the value from anywhere in the application by

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:anInt forKey:@"IntKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Then you can retrieve the value from anywhere in the application by

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults];
int a = [defaults integerForKey:@"IntKey"];
```

This also works great for `BOOL`, `float`, `NSString` and `NSArray`. Check out the [`NSUserDefaults` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Put the:

```
extern int val;
```

in at least one header file included by any .m or .c file where you want to use this global variable.  Including an assignment here is almost always an error.

Put

```
int val = 0;
```

outside any function or method scope, in exactly one .m or .c file included in your build.  No more.

If you access this variable often, and care about performance and battery life, using NSDefaults is several orders of magnitude slower than accessing a global variable.  Using the app delegate for singleton model objects is also somewhat slower, and produces slightly larger apps.